# Convert date from mm/dd/yyyy hh:mm:ss to dd/mm/yyyy

Tags: sql-server-2008, date, datetime, date-format, date-conversion

Original date is 8/25/2017 12:00:00 AM

I need to Convert from mm/dd/yyyy hh:mm:ss AM to dd/mm/yy

I tried Format(date, "dd/mm/yyyy") but its showing as 25/00/2017

Any ideas/help is much appreciated

Thanks
Aruna

Answer (score 2):

refer this link : [`Convert Functions`](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/func_convert.asp)

**CONVERT :** (this is the appropriate answer for conversion from mm/dd/yyyy hh:mm:ss AM to dd/mm/yy)

```
select CONVERT(VARCHAR(10),GETDATE(),103)
```

[image: image1]

**FORMAT:**

this is using FORMAT (can be used in SQL Server 2012 or above versions)

```
select FORMAT(GETDATE(), 'dd/MM/yyyy', 'en-us')
```

[image: image2]

Answer (score 1):

After a little bit of Google, you can find this. Hope this would help.

```
SELECT CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), GETDATE(), 103)
```

Source: http://www.sqlinfo.net/sqlserver/sql_server_SELECT-Formatting_Date_Time.php

Answer (score 1):

`MM` instead of `mm`. The former is months, the latter minutes.

```
DECLARE @mydate DateTime = '8/25/2017 12:00:00 AM'
SELECT FORMAT (@mydate, N'dd/MM/yyyy')
-- If you want the 2 digit year use yy instead of yy
SELECT FORMAT (@mydate, N'dd/MM/yy')
```

[Format Documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh213505.aspx).